# Wordpress theme header

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Esteem blog wordpress theme and the header title dont show in home page

In article page it is show the article title etc but in homepage nothing.

In the homepage I want in the header title the blog title: BlogTest

Comment: For your future questions read the StackOverflow's guidelines like: [What topics can I ask on StackOverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be an option given there in Appearance>**Customize** tab. Check their documentation if are unable to find it.

https://docs.themegrill.com/esteem/

Also have you checked the header.php file in the editor? It will be a lot better if your share your site link.

Comment: I found it, it is the main slogan in customize-header. Thanks for documentation.

Comment: Glad I could be of any help :)